# What model/year is this bike?

Tags: road-bike, identify-this-bike

[bike http://images.craigslist.org/01010_iSEhT1sECUO_600x450.jpg](http://images.craigslist.org/01010_iSEhT1sECUO_600x450.jpg)

What model/year is this bike?

I was wondering because the owner of the bike does not know!

Thank you :D

Comment: Probably late 90s.

Comment: Try using Bikepedia. By selecting the brand and model you can find out what years that model was produced. The components brand and level are listed along with the colors available that year.  It can take a bit of comparison between years but has proven pretty accurate.

Comment: I agree with Daniel.  It's likely a late 90s T500 or T700 http://bikepedia.com/QuickBike/BikeSpecs.aspx?year=1998&brand=Cannondale&model=T700  It looks like the fork has been replaced since it appears they are color matched on most of the Cannondale touring bikes.

Answer (score 1):

(I've never owned a cannondale bike) judging from the parts :

- a triple crankset
- bar end shifters
- cantilever brakes
- the rims seem wider than typical road bike rims.
- a long cage dérailleur to accommodate big cassette (Not sure since the pic isn't the drive side)

It's likely a touring bike, so it's probably a modified Cannondale SR300, or [Touring 1](http://www.cannondale.com/nam_en/touring-17)